# Service Fabric stateful service failing with FailFast

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I'm running a Service Fabric application in an Azure cluster. The application ran fine for a few days without any issues. However yesterday we noticed one of the services went to an "Error" state and has not since recovered.

The service is a Reliable Stateful Service, with 1 partition and 3 replicas (i.e., one primary, two secondary). The service implements a long-running RunAsync(), and reads and writes to/from many ReliableDictionary entries concurrently during RunAsync().

We have noticed the following error in the event log on the primary node:

```
Description: The application requested process termination through System.Environment.FailFast(string message).
Message: ProgressVectorEntry.Lsn == failureLsn
Stack:
   at System.Environment.FailFast(System.String)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.ProgressVector.FindSharedVector(Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.ProgressVector, Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.ProgressVector)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.ProgressVector.FindCopyModePrivate(Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.CopyContextParameters, Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.CopyContextParameters, Int64)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.ProgressVector.FindCopyMode(Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.CopyContextParameters, Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.CopyContextParameters, Int64)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.LoggingReplicator.GetLogRecordsToCopy(Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.ProgressVector, System.Fabric.Epoch, Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.LogicalSequenceNumber, Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.LogicalSequenceNumber, Int64, Int64, Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.LogicalSequenceNumber ByRef, Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.LogicalSequenceNumber ByRef, Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.IAsyncEnumerator`1<Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.LogRecord> ByRef, Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.BeginCheckpointLogRecord ByRef)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.LoggingReplicatorCopyStream+<GetNextAsyncSafe>d__3.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Start[[Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.LoggingReplicatorCopyStream+<GetNextAsyncSafe>d__3, Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.Impl, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]](<GetNextAsyncSafe>d__3 ByRef)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.LoggingReplicatorCopyStream.GetNextAsyncSafe(System.Threading.CancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.LoggingReplicatorCopyStream.GetNextAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken)
   at System.Fabric.StateProviderBroker+AsyncEnumerateOperationDataBroker.<BeginGetNext>b__8(System.Threading.CancellationToken)
   at System.Fabric.Interop.Utility.WrapNativeAsyncMethodImplementation(System.Func`2<System.Threading.CancellationToken,System.Threading.Tasks.Task>, IFabricAsyncOperationCallback, System.String, System.Fabric.Interop.InteropApi)
   at System.Fabric.StateProviderBroker+AsyncEnumerateOperationDataBroker.BeginGetNext(IFabricAsyncOperationCallback)
```

We've never observed this in our local development environments, so far we've only observed this in an Azure cluster.

1. What's happening here? It looks like corrupt replication info.
2. What could our code be doing that would cause this problem?

Comment: Are you writing to multiple dictionary entries on the same dictionary within a single transaction?

Comment: No, one entry per tx. Multiple concurrent tx to different entries in one dictionary.

Comment: OK, good to know. What you're seeing here is a general verification against false progress on a secondary. The best way for us to debug why this is being hit is to look at your cluster logs. Can you open a support ticket through the Azure Portal and include a link to this SO post? The support team should take it from there.

Comment: Support request created, thankyou very much for your help @VaclavTurecek :)

Comment: What was the outcome of this issue @AdrianHofman?

Comment: @TomKerkhove bug in SF, fixed in on-prem SF in a version released shortly after this question was raised, 2.3.301 if memory serves.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, interesting. Feel free to answer your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an issue in Service Fabric that was fixed in [5.3.311](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureservicefabric/2016/11/21/release-of-sdk-2-3-311-and-runtime-5-3-311-for-windows/).